# Constructor: function does not take 3 arguments

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

Why the lines  `"nota(sinais, subs, indices);"` tells that function does not take 3 arguments. I've defined a constructor with 3.

```
class Solucao{
        bool    *sinal;
        bool    *sublinhado;
        int     *indice;
public:
        Solucao(){sinal = sublinhado = NULL;  indice = NULL; };
        Solucao (bool *sinais, bool *subs, int *indices)
        {
            sinal = sinais;
            sublinhado = subs;
                indice = indices;
        };
};


void Balas(int n, int m, Vector<float> c, Vector<float> b, Matrix<float> A) {
No_Balas *J = NULL;
Solucao *nota();
bool *sinais = new bool[1];
bool *subs = new bool[1];
int *indices = new int[1];

Vector<int> pto_inicial(1);

    pto_inicial[0] = 0; 
    sinais[0] = 0;
    subs[0] = 0;
    indices[0] = 0;

nota(sinais, subs, indices);
}
```

Comment: In the line where you have declared the object seems not right.

Comment: It's a pointer use `new` like: `nota = new Solucao(sinais, subs, indices);` and not `nota(sinais, subs, indices);`

Answer (score 1):

The `nota` instance has a `Solucao*` type (i.e., it's a pointer -- I assume the extra parenthesis are a typo and that you weren't trying to declare a function) as opposed to a `Sulucao` type.

Based on your current code it seems like you're trying to do the following:

```
nota = new Solucao(sinais, subs, indices);
```

However, I'd probably recommend against using `new` unless you have a good reason to do so. Instead you could remove the `Solucao *nota();` and just construct it once you have all the required parameters:

```
Solucao nota(sinais, subs, indices);
```

---

**Note:** If you continue to use dynamic allocation (i.e., `new`) I'd recommend you use a C++11 compliant compiler and learn about the available smart pointers. For example:

```
std::unique_ptr<Solucao> nota = std::make_unique(sinais, subs, indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Solucao *nota();
```

This declares a function named `nota` that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to `Solucao`. So the compiler is right that it doesn't take 3 arguments.